# Multiples div con nombre dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

Tengo un div(scroleable) con un nombre de clase dinámico(que cambia en cada recarga de pagina) y necesito cambiar la posiciones del scroll.

El problema es que no se como llamarlo con javascript porque no tengo un id o algo parecido.
Puedo hacerlo getElementsByTagName, pero son muchos div mas de 100...

¿Como puedo saber cual es el indice de este div o de que manera puedo accesarlo?
Nota: no puedo recorrerlo con un for ya que trabajo con seleium y el javascript es limitado.
Div:

```
<div class="ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer contentContainer-103" data-is-scrollable="true">
```

Código con el cual puedo accesar al div, pero no tengo el indice:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].scrollTop = 500
```

Comment: Podrías utilizar el `document.querySelectorAll(elemento)` y ponerle con un `indexOf` del elemento que quieres ir hacia abajo (ejemplo: `document.querySelectorAll(".ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer").indexOf(document.getElementById("test"))`)

Comment: Hola:                                                                                                                                Muchas gracias, me diste una pista de como lograrlo.... document.querySelectorAll("div")   coloque esto en consola y me arrojo todas las clases de la ejecución (Recuerda que tengo elementos con nombres dinámicos que varían según la recarga) por ende necesitaba ver el indice.

Comment: Cuál es la parte dinámica del nombre? <div class="ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer contentContainer-103" Es el indice final lo que cambia (el 103) ? Prueba a buscarlo por css $("div[class^='contentContainer-']")